# Wrong limit involving sine?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Using Mathematica 9.0.0.0, I was trying to calculate the sum
$$
B_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \sin^4\left(\frac{(i-1)}{(n-1)}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right).
$$
where I thought it would be $B_n = \frac{3(n-1) + 4}{8}$.

I did it using

```
res[n_] = Sum[Sin[(i - 1) Pi / (2 (n - 1))]^4, {i, 1, n}] - (3 (n - 1) + 4)/8 // Simplify
DiscretePlot[res[n], {n, 2, 100}]
Limit[res[m], m -> Infinity]
```

It can be seen in the discrete plot that my assumption about $B_n$ is reasonable, since the residual `res` is zero for $n=2,\dots,100$. Furthermore, as can be seen in [this question on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762444/sum-over-fourth-power-of-the-sine), my assumption can be proved. Unfortunately, the limit of `res` is wrongly evaluated to $-\frac1{16}$. Is this something I just don't understand or did I find a bug?

---

By setting $m=n-1$ we get the sum
$$B_{n+1} = A_m = \sum_{j=0}^m \sin^4\left(\frac{j}{m}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
where the Limit is evaluated correctly:

```
a[m_] = Sum[Sin[j Pi / (2 m)]^4, {j, 0, m}] - (3 m + 4)/8 // Simplify
DiscretePlot[a[m], {m, 2, 100}]
Limit[a[m], m -> Infinity]
```

Comment: In MMA 10.4.0 the limit above does *not* return -1/16 (good news!) but instead just runs forever (not so good news :-( ). The limit in the second part of your question still returns zero immediately. I do have a followup question though: when $n=1$, the closed form of $B_n=0$, but the Sum has an indeterminate value, unless I am missing some trig magic, so how do you conflate the two?

Comment: I think it's a bug. `Series[res[n], {n, Infinity, 1}]` gets it right, but `Limit` seems to ask for the expansion out to degree `1/n^100`, which takes a real long time, unless time-constrained.